# How to construct Multiple variable barplot in r studio for the following data Table

Tags: bar-chart

[Two way table showing BMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghZXn.png)

[Need a barplot like this for the above table instead of "clarity" I want to put "Category"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjMw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and include any code you've written so far and your data using `dput()`. Please avoid posting images of data/code. Make sure to tag your questions with `[r]` if your question is relevant to R programming.

Comment: Hi... Many thanks. Sure will do that.